# Почему selenium не видит тег?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Есть сайт https://www.myscore.ru/. Решил распарсить с сайта результаты футбольных матчей с помощью селениума в учебных целях, но никак не могу сделать всё "красиво". Во вкладке "завершенные" получается найти все игры, которые не скрыты. Для того чтобы раскрыть игры какой-либо лиги нужно ткнуть на span, но никак не получается его найти, хоть даже тег обладает собственным классом "expand-league".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот часть кода:

```
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('li2').click()
ended = driver.find_element_by_class_name('table-main').find_elements_by_class_name('soccer')
for item in ended:
    try:
        league = item.find_element_by_class_name('expand-league')
        league.click()
        print(league.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('.NoSuchElementException')
    except WebDriverException:
        print('WebDriverException')
    games = item.find_elements_by_class_name('stage-finished')
    for game in games:
        print(game.text)
```

Comment: expand-league-link же?

Comment: это общий спан, в который обернут другой. expand-league меняется на collapse-league если игры раскрыты